# Prove or disprove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3x^n$ is uniformly convergent for $x\in(-1,1)$

Tags: power-series, uniform-convergence

> Prove or disprove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3x^n$ is uniformly convergent on $x\in(-1,1)$

I started with proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3x^n$ is convergent.

By ratio test:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^3x^{n+1}}{n^3x^n}|=|x|\cdot|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}|=|x|<1$$

so we get $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3x^n$ converges.

Now, I tried proving that it is uniformly convergent, I wanted to use the M-test, but I couldn't find a suitable series for the test. If the interval was $[-t,t]$ such that $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then I could do: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3x^n\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3t^n$, and we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3t^n$ converges because of the ratio test above. But this is not the case. Please help!

Comment: You say uniformly continuous in the title but uniformly convergent in the body. Which?

Comment: convergent, my bad

Comment: If it was uniformly convergent it would be bounded, but it is unbounded as $x \to 1$. Note that for $x>0$ then the sum is always larger than $n^3 x^n$ for any $n$.

Comment: So you are saying its not uniformly convergent?

Comment: You need to do a little bit of work :-).

Comment: What work? The major problem I'm having right now is this, because after I get this done, I need to find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^3x^n$ But I want to try it without help, using part-by-part integration, and those stuff.. But to use this, I have to prove that $\sum n^3x^n$ uniformly convergent

Comment: If it unbounded, which I have shown, then it cannot be uniformly convergent.

Comment: If you had to write in your H.W why the sum is *not* uniformly convergent, how would you write it, because if thats the case, then I will send my tutor, who gave this question - to calculate $\sum n^3x^n$

Comment: I would show why being uniformly convergent implies boundedness and then show that it is unbounded. As I have written above.

Comment: But isn't it obvious that it should be bounded becuase otherwise $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^3x^n\neq0$? And if so, when $x\to1$ then it is still bounded, no?

Comment: @copper.hat why does uniform convergence imply boundedness? $1/x \to 1/x$ is uniformly convergent and is not bounded?

Comment: @psl2Z Here is a hint: The interval $(-1,1)$ is bounded, so is covered by a finite number of sets of the form $(a,a+\delta)$.

Comment: Maybe your tutor meant to ask you to show that there is uniform convergence on $[-r,r]$ for all $0 < r < 1$, since that is true and close to what he currently asked? Though at this point it's just re-showing standard properties of power series.

Comment: @psl2Z I have no idea what you mean by ${1 \over x} \to {1 \over x}$.

Comment: @psl2Z the key point is that each partial sum, which is a polynomial thus continuous, is bounded on $[-1,1]$, thus on $(-1,1)$. So we would be dealing with uniform convergence of bounded functions, and thus the limit would be bounded, but the pointwise limit clearly isn't bounded, thus there is no uniform convergence on the whole of $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @BrunoB yes, I see. So in this special case it implies boundedness

Comment: @psl2Z What do you mean by "$1/x\to 1/x$
 is uniformly convergent and is not bounded"? That not how you define a function, let alone a **sequence** of functions, which is the subject of the question.

Comment: @jjagmath define $f_n(x):=1/x$ for $x\in (0,\infty)$. Then $f_n \to 1/x$ uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ and $1/x$ not bounded on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Someone already answered, my real problem was to calculate the sum of $\sum n^3x^n$ but to do so I needed to use part-by-part integration, and to do so I needed to prove that the sum is uniformly converges. After someone answered, I understood that even tho it doesn't uniformly converges, the sum of $\sum$ on $(-1,1)$ is equal to the sum $[-a,a]\forall 0<a<1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false.

Let $S_n(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^3x^k$, next, we show $S_n(x)$ is NOT uniformly convergent on $(-1,1)$. Consider the remainder

$$R_n(x)=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty k^3x^k$$

If $S_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent, it means

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N$, $\forall n>N,\forall x\in (0,1)\Rightarrow|R_n(x)|<\epsilon, $.

We want to prove it is NOT uniformly convergent, so we negate it,

$\exists\epsilon>0, \forall N, \exists n>N, \exists x\in (0,1)\Rightarrow|R_n(x)|\ge\epsilon$.

Choose $\epsilon=1, n=N+1, x=1-\frac{1}{N+2}$,

$$|R_n(x)|=|R_{N+1}(x)|=\left|\sum_{k=N+2}^\infty k^3\left(1-\frac{1}{N+2}\right)^k\right|\ge (N+2)^3\left(1-\frac{1}{N+2}\right)^{N+2}\to\infty>1$$